# No such file or directory on Mac terminal for python

Tags: python, python-3.x

`hello.py` is my first python program. It is saved on my desktop.

In the terminal I write in front of

```
user@AA-MacBook-Air ~ % python3 hello.py
```

The error is

```
can't open file 'hello.py': [Errno 2] No such file or directory
```

Kindly help me understand the problem and solve it.

Comment: `cd Desktop` then try and run your program.

Comment: `hello.py` is not in the current directory.

Comment: The `~` in your prompt means you are in your home directory. The script you are trying to run is apparently in your desktop directory. So use the command `cd Desktop` to go to the correct directory, and you should be able to run your program from there.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the terminal you are currently in the directory `~`. This signifies the folder `/Users/<username>`. Your script is on your desktop.

Type `cd Desktop` to change to `/Users/<username>/Desktop` and then run `python3 hello.py`.

Comment: It worked!! Thank you for helping out!! I just ran my first program, I wouldn't have been able to do so without your help. :) Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

you first need to change destination with cd

Answer (score 1):

The error message, `No such file or directory` pretty much gives the explanation. Check if the file `hello.py` is present in the correct working directory. This can done graphically or using the `ls` command. If it is not present, copy the file the to the directory or navigate to the location of the file `hello.py` in terminal using `cd`.

Comment: Thank you for your help. :) How do I find which is the correct working directory?

Comment: Type `pwd` for it.

Comment: alright, thank you so much :) you have been very helpful, thanks :)